# Rotate Image Captured Using Camera in Kotlin Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

In Kotlin Android Studio, whenever I take an image using the camera and display it in the image view, it gets rotated 90degree to the left.

I have implemented a `ExitInterface` to check for orientation associated with the image captured but I am unsure of my next course of action on how to solve this.

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
import android.media.ExifInterface
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.Matrix

class FormActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    ...
    var photoUri : Uri? = null

    companion object {
        const val REQUEST_FROM_CAMERA = 1001
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_form)

        ...
        val cameraBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.cameraBtn)

        // launch the camera
        cameraBtn.setOnClickListener {
            takePicture()
        }
    }

    private fun takePicture(){
        ImagePicker.with(this).cameraOnly()
            .crop()
            .start(REQUEST_FROM_CAMERA)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            when (requestCode){
                REQUEST_FROM_CAMERA -> {
                    photoUri = data!!.data
                    val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, photoUri)
                    val bitmapDrawable = BitmapDrawable(bitmap)

                    val photoImageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.photoImageView)


                    // use ExitInterface to check for orientation associated with the image captured
                    val ei = ExifInterface(photoImageView)
                    val orientation: Int = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED)

                    var rotatedBitmap: Bitmap? = null
                    when (attr.orientation) {
                        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90 -> rotatedBitmap =
                            rotateImage(attr.bitmap, 90)
                        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180 -> rotatedBitmap =
                            rotateImage(attr.bitmap, 180)
                        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270 -> rotatedBitmap =
                            rotateImage(attr.bitmap, 270)
                        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL -> rotatedBitmap = attr.bitmap
                        else -> rotatedBitmap = attr.bitmap
                    }

                    // display the image taken
                    photoImageView.setImageDrawable(bitmapDrawable)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun rotateImage(source: Bitmap, angle: Float): Bitmap? {
        val matrix = Matrix()
        matrix.postRotate(angle)
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(
            source, 0, 0, source.width, source.height,
            matrix, true
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: What should be solved? You already check for orientation information and rotate the bitmap accordingly. So you are done i would say.

Answer (score 0):

try `ImageDecoder` for Android sdk versions above Pie

```
    val imageBitmap: Bitmap = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
            requireContext().contentResolver,
            imageUri
        )
    } else {
        val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(
            requireContext().contentResolver,
            imageUri
        )
        ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
    }
```

to compress and save to a file,

```
    var quality = 100
    var stream: OutputStream
    do {
        stream = FileOutputStream(newTempFile)
        imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, stream)
        quality -= 3
    } while (selectedUploadImageFile!!.length() > 2000000)
    stream.flush()
    stream.close()
```